# Is there a way to retire old tags?

Tags: tags

I would like to retire some old tags I used to use. Is there a way to migrate them to a new tag, or even better, remove them from previous posts?

Answer (score 1):

From the dashboard, under Posts on the right, is a Tags screen. From there delete or edit specific tags.